# TransitionSet ArrayList.size() on a null object reference

Tags: android, kotlin, android-transitions

Started realization for open images with Shared Elements and animation by this guide.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/continuous-shared-element-transitions.html

But catched an exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
at android.support.transition.TransitionSet.setDuration(TransitionSet.java:196)
at android.support.transition.TransitionSet.setDuration(TransitionSet.java:60)
at android.support.transition.Transition.<init>(Transition.java:278)
at android.support.transition.TransitionSet.<init>(TransitionSet.java:91)
at android.support.transition.TransitionInflater.createTransitionFromXml(TransitionInflater.java:151)
at android.support.transition.TransitionInflater.inflateTransition(TransitionInflater.java:70)
```

When call

```
TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(R.transition.my_transition)
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Found nothing on this problem from the Google, that why i post this.

Problem was in duration parameter.

You can fix it like this:

Need to remove duration from xml, and set it after TransitionSet created in code.

```
val transition = TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(R.transition.my_transition)
transition.duration = 325
```

Hope helped someone.

Comment: Looks like you were following this blog too. https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/continuous-shared-element-transitions.html  . Thanks for the help.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 50X. That was such an annoying little bug. Note this can be shortened a bit using `.apply{ duration = 325L }`

Answer (score 5):

In my case this error was happening because I had imported TransitionInflator from

```
import android.support.transition.TransitionInflater
```

While it should be imported from

```
import android.transition.TransitionInflater
```

When I fixed the import, the error got resolved.